# Are cyclic quadrilaterals halved by this polygonal chain?

Tags: geometry

I tried to help one of my friends with her exercise, who is actually younger than me, but I can't figure it out myself. The problem is the following:

We have a cyclic quadrilateral, whose diagonals are perpendicular. Is the ABCO quadrilateral's area half the whole? This can also be proved by showing that the areo of the ABCO and AOCD is the same.

[image]

After some heavy thinking I am currently at the following state:
[image]

I now that the whole's area is $\frac{x*y}{2}$, which must be equal to the following, kind of ugly expression:
$$2*(\frac{x*\sqrt{r^2-\frac{x^2}{4}}}{2}+\frac{x*cos(45°+\frac12arccos(\frac{y}{2r})*cos(45°-\frac12arccos(\frac{y}{2r}))*r}{2})$$

Now I'm sure it can be solved (and by replacing the variables I get a near-correct result to the area according to geogebra), but I don't think that it would be the most elegant solution, there might be some shorter ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of a cyclic orthodiagonal quadrilateral is given by $\frac{1}{2}(ac + bd)$, where $a,b,c,d$ are the side lengths.

On the other hand, the altitudes from $O$ to each side have length equal to half of the opposite side. That means that the area of quadrilateral $ABCO$ is given by $\frac{1}{2}a(\frac{c}{2}) + \frac{1}{2}b(\frac{d}{2}) = \frac{1}{4}(ac + bd)$.

Comment: Which threorem states the one about altitudes? Or should I just have a look at it and try to solve? As it doesn't look that hard to prove.

Comment: @FloriOn No, it isn't too hard to prove. In particular, try showing that $\angle ODC = \angle ACB$. Then, dropping altitudes from $O$ to $AB$ and $CD$ gives congruent right triangles, and the result follows.